# Protected get-functions for protected datamembers?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

We have two classes(A and B). Class A can only be created by classes who inherit from it(class A)
and class B can be created by a user.

Class A, version 1 has a **private** data member and has methods to aces the data in class A.

Class A, version 2 has a **protected** data member and therefore, no methods are needed for classes that will inherit from the class to aces the data in class A

**Class A, version 1**

```
class A
{
protected:
   A() = default;

   void set_data( T d );
   T& get_data();
private:
   T data;  
}
```

**Class A, version 2**

```
class A
{
protected:
   A() = default;

   T data;  
}
```

**Class B**

```
class B : public A {}
```

Which version of class A is the preferred one?

Comment: I think the inheritance is irrelevant here. This is equivalent to the decision of whether to have getters/setters or make a member public. Depends whether you might need to impose invariants on the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version one is always preferred. Data members of class should by default be `private`. Making data members all public is justified only in one case i.e If you just want to bundle-o-data. Only then you would use `struct` and make all data public. ( Like to capture the essence of what is s single node in linked list)

However, there is no such exception in case of `protected`. You can always make them private and provide accessors/mutators to those data members.

Downside of `public` data members is that they breaks the encapsulation. And it's difficult to maintain *invariants* as data is open to modification from all sides. Case of `protected` data member is bit restrictive than `public` in that it opens up ways for modification only through derived class members and friends. But still it's breaking encapsulation.

Conclusion :- All data members of class should always be `private` except in case it's intended to be used as `bundle-o-data`.

Along with that you would never want to pass handle to your internals to outside users as you have done in:-

```
T& get_data();
```

So, better way would be

```
const T& get_data();
```

except in some specific scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly subjective, but I would say 95% of the time neither one. Protected data makes your code just as hard to maintain as public so we rule that version out right away. But then also you almost never need a direct mutator (set) function, so we'll chop that function and then change the signature of the get function to `const T& get_data() const;`. Then we'll add a *real* interface to the parent to manipulate its state rather than having something external decide what the new state should be.

Comment: very much agree here. A simple get/set pair is logically equivalent to an exposed 'data is interface' member. Striving to make as many classes invariant as possible is good practice. If the class must be mutable then its updates are likely to be complex and have dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the common guidelines, data members should be private. Therefore, version 1 is preferred. On the other hand, completely trivial get/set pairs are a minor code smell in my opinion, so you may want to investigate why that member needs to be fully exposed to the derived class in the first place.

Comment: Exactly. If your get is just `return m_value` and your set is `m_value = value`, then you don't need them. (Unless you're trying to maintain style)

Answer (score 0):

Use accessor functions if you need anything other than simple access to the variable: validating the value, maintaining class invariants, signalling changes, logging, etc. Note that `get` should return either a value or a `const` reference; your version, returning a non-const reference, can be used to assign arbitrary values to the variable, bypassing the `set` function.

If you only need simple access then some would suggest exposing the variable for the sake of simplicity; others would suggest using accessor functions for the sake of consistency (with other types that do need such things), or backwards compatibility (if you later decide you need functions after all). There's no compelling reason to prefer either option.